# Widgets of installed apps do not appear in list

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, app-widgets

I just bought my father a chinese phone, seems to be working great except after I install an app, it does not appear in the widgets list.
I have tried several apps (Wifi Manager, Gsam Battery monitor) on several launchers (Default, Zeam, GO Launcher EX). I even set English instead of Hungarian, nothing helped.
The default widgets (Bookmarks, Calendar, Gmail, etc) are in the list.

Is there some setting I am missing?

Comment: Maybe. You didn't move those apps to SDCard somehow? Unlikely, but the first thing coming to my mind when widgets do not show up...

Comment: It was the default setting somehow. Thank you very much. If you convert it to an answer, I will accept it as a solution. Someone else might profit from it.

Comment: Sure thing – glad my guess was a precision landing, and thus the solution an easy one! Done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can (and certainly will) happen when installing apps on SDCard. Normally, the system should prevent this (or rather the dev, by defining the "install-location" accordingly in the app's `Manifest`).

So if the apps were installed on SDCard, go to *Settings→Apps*, scroll to the apps' entries, open them (one by one), and move the app to internal storage. If the widgets do not appear right away after that, they should do so at least after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Izzy is right, by default you aren't able to load widgets from external memory. If you'd like to do that you will have to use an app like link2sd or something to trick the kernel into thinking it is the internal memory.

[Link2sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en)

[link2sd +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.link2sdplus&hl=en)